# Why is method postProcessAfterInitialization of BeanPostProcessor not called?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need help in writing my own BeanPostProcessor. In my controller I get `@RequestParam String query` which I need to preprocess before further request processing. Here is my Annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface UTF8DecodeQuery {
}
```

Also I've written BPP to handle this annotation in runtime:

```
@Component
public class UTF8DecodeQueryAnnotationBeanPostProcessor 
implements IUTF8QueryDecryptor, BeanPostProcessor, Ordered {
  private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, Class<?>> 
  bean2class = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

  public UTF8DecodeQueryAnnotationBeanPostProcessor() {
     System.out.println("BPP constructor called");
  }

  @Override
  public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object 
  bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
     if(Arrays.stream(bean.getClass().getMethods())
         .anyMatch(m -> m.isAnnotationPresent(UTF8DecodeQuery.class)))
        bean2class.put(beanName, bean.getClass());
     return bean;
  }

  @Override
  public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object 
  bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
     System.out.println("BPP after initialization called");
     Class<?> aclass = bean2class.get(beanName);
     if(aclass != null) {
       return Enhancer.create(aclass, (MethodInterceptor) (obj, method, args, methodProxy) -> {
      if(method.isAnnotationPresent(UTF8DecodeQuery.class)) {
       //Some processing logic
       //changing one of args
       //Some processing logic
       }
       return methodProxy.invoke(bean, args);
});
     }
     return bean
  }
}
```

I annotated method in `@RestController` implementation.
The problem is that method `postProcessBeforeInitialization` is really called (btw I can see, that bean of my rest controller is presence in Map), but method `postProcessAfterInitialization` is never called.
Please help me!
P.S. I don't want to use AOP and to avoid using BPP, it is of rather educational purposes than of critical need

Comment: You don't want to use AOP but you are, more or less, already using AOP, bu the proxy creation and decoding. Also this is better handled in a specialized `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`. That being said the method should be called, but is it really not called? Or is the controller not enhanced (which is actually a bit dangerous with the annotaitons on there, that might actually break SpringMVC not being able to read the annotations anymore).

Comment: @M. Deinum Thank you for your comment. Yes, method is not called, breakpoint and absence of `"BPP after initialization called"` in stdout are evidence of not calling. Could you explain your last sentence? Sorry, this was my first experience with BPP.

Comment: In the BPP you are creating a proxy of the actual class. As (some) annotations aren't inherited this could pose a problem for Spring MVC to detect them. But as stated none-the-less it should be invoked, is your context fully started? You also implement multiple interfaces, although it shouldn't be a problem it could be.

Comment: But Spring detects them, as Map is not empty, it contains exactly one bean with method marked with my annotation. As I have said, `postProcessBeforeInitialization` is called and works correctly (checked in debug mode). My context is fully started, the application works fine except this part